# show camera and camera-roll icon in IOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a Swift application that takes photo from either the camera or photo library. I use `UIImagePickerController()` with `sourceType = .Camera` or `sourceType = .PhotoLibrary`. This would show the camera or photo-library, respectively.

However, in some other apps, user can switch between camera and photo-library from within the camera view, by clicking an icon below the camera. I'm including some screenshots below just to sho examples.

**Can UIImagePickerController be customized from Swift code to show a similar dialog?**

this is the picker of some messaging app:

"[image: this is whatsapp picker]

and this is the Camera app with an icon on the lower left section that sends user to photo library

[image: this is the Camera app with an icon on the lower left section]

Comment: Nope. You'd have to build that yourself. Personally I'd strongly recommend against doing so. Cameras are a ton of work to get right. If possible, redesign your flow to accomodate the system constraints.

Comment: @OscarApeland thanks. This is an answer as impossibility is valid answer to a "How" question. Please add this as an answer and I'd accept it.

Comment: This is relatively easy to accomplish. There are a few duplicates about this. It involves showing the button using `cameraOverlayView`.  You can use the button to display a PHPickerViewController.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sadly, no. You'd have to build that yourself from scratch. Personally I'd strongly recommend against doing so. Cameras and Photos are a ton of work to get right. If possible, redesign your flow to accomodate the system solutions with UIImagePickerController and PHPickerController.

Comment: Not sure why the OP accepted this answer. This simply isn't true. You do not need to build your own camera or your own photo picker.

Comment: @HangarRash Please read the question. OP is asking if its possible to modify the SDK pickers to display the behaviour from the attached apps. Modifying UIImagePickerController's camera is disallowed and not really possible anyway. If he wanted that behaviour, he'd have to build a replica from scratch (or use some third party framework, but iOS OSS is ass)

Comment: I did read the question and what the OP wants to do is possible. UIImagePickerController provides the `cameraOverlayView` property which makes it easy to add the additional button. That's all that's needed. When the button is tapped, you can present the photo picker. No custom replicas needed.